# What is the phenomenon called when we use an incorrect sensory perception to describe something?

Tags: adjectives, sense-verbs

My primary and most common example is to read something and say (or write) that it "sounds familiar". Text has no sound. I'm sure there is a technical term for this practice or phenomenon. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical term you're thinking of is [synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia)

> a neurologically based condition in which stimulation of one sensory or cognitive pathway leads to automatic, involuntary experiences in a second sensory or cognitive pathway.

...but you don't really want to say that. Your usages are simply [metaphoric](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metaphor)

> a figure of speech in which a term or phrase is applied to something to which it is not literally applicable in order to suggest a resemblance.

Everyone does this all the time, often without realising. A blind friend of mine only occasionally registers the fact that he says *"I see what you mean"* as often as anyone else.

One broad classification of metaphors is into *cognitive* (involving thought, meaning, purpose, etc.) as opposed to *perceptual* (based on sense perceptions). **Perceptual metaphors** can be further subdivided into [visual, auditory, olfactory, gustatory, tactile,](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual%20auditory%20olfactory%20tactile%20metaphor&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22perceptual%20metaphor%22%20linguistics&pbx=1&oq=%22perceptual%20metaphor%22%20linguistics&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=31807l34599l2l35357l12l12l0l0l0l0l130l775l10.2l12l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=341b3c5e7f789731&biw=1359&bih=842) etc. I'm not aware of a single term for metaphors where both the thing referenced, and the metaphor, involve different sensory inputs.

Comment: Synesthesia is the neurological mixing or confusion of senses, and is experienced as real for the subject. I'm just looking for a term, maybe in vain, for this type of 'synesthesiac metaphor'.

Comment: Well if you're sure there is a specific term for 'sensory crossover' metaphors, I'm in no position to say there won't be, but I've either never come across it or I didn't remember it. *Visual metaphor*, for example, is an extremely common term, but *auditory metaphor* less so, and *olfactory/tactile/gustatory metaphor* hardly exists at all. In the end I think the best you'll get is **perceptual metaphor**, so I'll amend the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, *perceptual metaphor* seems appropriate[1], but although I'm no linguist, I just see *metaphor* as something more intentional, i.e. not used erroneously, consciously or not.

[1] Funny enough, somebody elsewhere suggested *malapropism*.

Comment: Perhaps Mustafa wasn't so wrong after all! It seems to me you're narrowing your requirement to *dead perceptual metaphors*. Now I truly will be gobsmacked if anyone turns up a specific single word for that! *Malapropisms* are genuine mistakes - a blind person saying *"I see what you mean"* is normal use of language.

Answer (score 0):

I perceive it as "**dead metaphor**"  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor)

Comment: -1: A "dead metaphor" (somewhat recursive, given it's a metaphoric usage itself!) simply means a metaphoric usage that's become so common people often don't even realise it *is* metaphoric. OP is specifically looking for a term to describe *only those metaphors that refer to one type of sensory input in terms of another sense*.